# Hiding small top part of ruby tag when line-clamp is applied

Tags: html, css

When using with line-camp on ruby tag, the small part of the ruby tag is visible when the main characters are hidden. I tried to add max-height to the text and it worked in chrome but it's not working correctly in Safari sometime. I'm not sure what is the right approach. Any idea how can I resolve this issue. Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="description" content="baru belajar html"
    <title>Hello World! </title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div>
      <h6 style="-webkit-line-clamp: 1; overflow: hidden; line-height:1.75rem;
      width: 50px; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical">
          <ruby><rb>日本語</rb><rp>(</rp><rt>にほんご</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>
          <ruby><rb>日本語</rb><rp>(</rp><rt>にほんご</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>
          <ruby><rb>日本語</rb><rp>(</rp><rt>にほんご</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>
          <ruby><rb>日本語</rb><rp>(</rp><rt>にほんご</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>
      </h6>
    </div>
    
     <div>
      <h6 style="-webkit-line-clamp: 1; overflow: hidden; line-height:1.75rem;
      max-height: 1.75rem;
      width: 50px; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical">
          <ruby><rb>日本語</rb><rp>(</rp><rt>にほんご</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>
          <ruby><rb>日本語</rb><rp>(</rp><rt>にほんご</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>
          <ruby><rb>日本語</rb><rp>(</rp><rt>にほんご</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>
          <ruby><rb>日本語</rb><rp>(</rp><rt>にほんご</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>
      </h6>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```